# como hago una lista enlazada para que me convierta los dígitos en clave murciélago en c++

Tags: dev-c++

Elabore una función que lea caracteres desde teclado, hasta que el usuario ya no quiera seguir introduciéndoles. Estos caracteres corresponden a una palabra que hay que traducir utilizando la clave del murciélago. Cada carácter se debe colocar en un nodo de una lista lineal simplemente enlazada. Por ejemplo, si se introduce la palabra mango, se tendrá una lista con los caracteres 0, 7,n, 8 y 9. Debe implementar inserción de nodos al final de la lista, para que, al recorrerla en sentido directo y desplegar, se vea la palabra codificada escrita en el sentido correcto.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el ejercicio según lo entendí, utilizando una lista enlazada simple.

- Primero cree el struct nodo que representa el nodo para la lista
- Lo que hace la función traducir es recibir una letra e intercambiarla por un número según la clave 'MURCIELAGO
- La función insertar final agrega un nodo al final de la lista enlazad, eso para que a la hora de mostrarlo salga en el orden deseado.
- La función reportar lista muestra en pantalla la lista que se le envía por parámetro
- En la función main lo primero es recibir letras hasta que el usuario inserte un 0 (cero), entonces se mostrará la lista en clave 'MURCIELAGO'

.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct nodo
{
  char letra;
  struct nodo *sgte;
};
typedef struct nodo *Tlista;


char traducir(char letra){
    char arr[10] = { 'M', 'U', 'R', 'C', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'O' };
    char arr2[10] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    char l;
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      if (letra == arr[j])
        {
          return arr2[j];
        }
    }
    return letra;
}
void
insertarFinal (Tlista & lista, int valor)
{
  Tlista t, q = new (struct nodo);

  q->letra = valor;
  q->sgte = NULL;

  if (lista == NULL)
    {
      lista = q;
    }
  else
    {
      t = lista;
      while (t->sgte != NULL)
    {
      t = t->sgte;
    }
      t->sgte = q;
    }

}

void
reportarLista (Tlista lista)
{
  Tlista lista1 = NULL;
  int i = 0;


  while (lista != NULL)
    {

      cout << ' ' << i + 1 << ") " << traducir(lista->letra) << endl;
      lista = lista->sgte;
      i++;
    }
}



int
main ()
{
  Tlista lista = NULL;
  char _dato = '-';

  while (true)
    {
      cout << "Ingrese una letra: ";
      cin >> _dato;
      if (_dato == '0')
    {
      break;
    }
      insertarFinal (lista, _dato);
    }

  reportarLista (lista);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad pues por ejemplo hace difícil entender el como tu script soluciona el problema plnateado, considera leer [answer], editar y explicar